# Where_Clause expression working for one FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion export but not another

Tags: arcpy, export, where-clause, subset

I am attempting to export a feature class to both a shapefile and feature class with a where_clause restriction on particular values within particular fields. I have written a function to take dataset paths and export subsets for particular datasets.

I am getting correct/incorrect outputs depending on the particular dataset that is passed to the function. I have triple checked field names/values and implemented AddFieldDelimiters to try to circumvent dataset format differences.

The code can be viewed below:

```
def export_data_retain_fields(dataset, output_directory):
    print("Exporting {} to {} directory".format(dataset, output_directory))
    dataset_fname = DCM_sde_new_names[dataset.split('.')[-1]].replace('DCP_TRD_', '')

    '''
    Below section of code doesn't work. Defining field names in sql 
    expressions require specific formatting depending on if
    the data is in shapefile or feature class format. The AddFieldDelimiters 
    method allows you to not have to format your
    sql expression to account for if it's a shapefile or feature class
    '''

    if dataset == DCM_sde_path:
        print("Restricting Feature Type and Type fields for 
        {}".format(dataset_fname))
        sql_expression = """Type <> 'Former_ROW' AND Feature_type <> 'Demapped_St'"""

        # Here is where I declare export with where_clause equal to sql_expression defined above. This DOESN'T work

        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(dataset, output_directory,
                                                 dataset_fname, where_clause=sql_expression)

    '''
    Below section of code works. Defining field names in sql expressions 
    require specific formatting depending on if
    the data is in shapefile or feature class format. The AddFieldDelimiters 
    method allows you to not have to format your
    sql expression to account for if it's a shapefile or feature class
    '''

    if dataset == DCM_SCL_sde_path:
        print("Restricting Route Type and Feature Status for 
        {}".format(dataset_fname))
        sql_expression = """Route_type <> 'Former_ROW' AND Feature_status <> 'Demapped'"""
        print(sql_expression)

        # Here is where I declare export with where_clause equal to sql_expression defined above. This DOES work

        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(dataset, output_directory,
                                                dataset_fname, where_clause=sql_expression)
    else:
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(dataset, output_directory,
                                                dataset_fname)
```

The function works correctly for the DCM_SCL_sde dataset path but returns the full dataset (omits the subset) for the DCM_sde dataset path. I have triple checked field names and values and have not been able to find any discrepancies.

I have ran the same exact query directly in ArcMap and got a correct data subset to export. I also attempted to use Select_analysis with arcpy rather than FeatureClassToFeatureClass with no success.

Comment: Can you try it without the automated field delimiters?  Just hard-code the delimiters in the SQL string and see if that works.  Then you can rule that in or out as a contributor to the problem.  If you rule it out, then you can remove it from your test code, to simplify the code to make it easier to further diagnose.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your speedy reply. I just removed the delimiters and re-ran and got the same result. The DCM export receives no subset and the DCM_SCL export receives the appropriate subset so it seems like it's not an issue with those. I appreciate your help

Comment: It may be worth editing your question to use the simplified version of your code then (without delimiters code).  It will make it easier to read and diagnose.  (Always post the minimal code required to reproduce the problem.)

Comment: I have gone ahead and edited the above code block to reflect this change. Also one thing I forgot to mention is that the source datasets are being pulled from ArcSDE feature classes. Thank you for the help and suggestions!

Comment: Just to check... I assume that `DCM_sde_path` is a direct path to the SDE feature class, and not a layer?  I have found that using a layer **with a join** can have odd unexpected behaviours with some arcpy functions.

Comment: Yup, direct path to the feature class within the SDE and not a layer. Thanks again

Comment: If you remove the else statement, do you still get output for the sde layer?  I'm wondering if there is an issue with the sde path that is causing your code to jump to the else statement, which doesn't include the where clause.

Comment: On top of jbalk's comment, I would add a print statement just before your if blocks, say `print("{}--{}--{}".format(dataset, DCM_sde_path, DCM_SCL_sde_path))`.

Comment: jbalk was correct. Commenting out the else statement fixed the issue. I added the print statement before my if block as suggested by faith_dur but dataset does equal DCM_sde_path (I use the same variable when calling the function) so I don't really know why this behavior is observed. Thank you to everyone who helped. Now I need to figure out how to get this else working.